# Macro strange behavior

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a very simple macro which essentially opens two XLS files and then copy some ranges from them and paste this information into another ranges in the destination file. The issue here is that macro is running well, but the last range is pasted in 'Selection" sheet, instead of be done in the sheet indicated in the code. I can't figure out what's happening, because I have a clone workbook (the macro here only varies a few ranges) and it's doing its work very well.

```
Sub CopySheets()
On Error GoTo eh
Dim Path As String
Dim FileA As String
Dim FileB As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Filename2 As String
Dim SheetSource5 As String
Dim SheetDest5 As String

'Defining Strings

Path = Sheets("Config").Range("C2").Value
FileA = Sheets("Selection").Range("G23").Value
FileB = Sheets("Selection").Range("H23").Value
Filename = Path & FileA & ".xlsx"
Filename2 = Path & FileB & ".xlsx"
SheetSource1 = "MS1"
SheetSource2 = "MS2"
SheetSource3 = "MS3"
SheetSource4 = "MS4"
SheetSource5 = "MS5"
SheetDest1 = "CTO"
SheetDest2 = "EPSO"
SheetDest3 = "ASO"
SheetDest4 = "SO"
SheetDest5 = "GCCO"


'Defining Current Workbook

Set cwb = ThisWorkbook

'First Import

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename)

wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource1).Range("L8:M117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource1).Range("R8:R117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest1).Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource1).Range("W8:W117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest1).Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource2).Range("L8:M117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource2).Range("R8:R117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest2).Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource2).Range("W8:W117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest2).Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource3).Range("L8:M117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest3).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource3).Range("R8:R117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest3).Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource3).Range("W8:W117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest3).Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource4).Range("L8:M117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest4).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource4).Range("R8:R117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest4).Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource4).Range("W8:W117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest4).Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource5).Range("L8:M117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest5).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource5).Range("R8:R117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest5).Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource5).Range("W8:W117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest5).Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


'Second Import

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename2)

wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource1).Range("L8:M117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest1).Range("A112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource1).Range("R8:R117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest1).Range("C112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource1).Range("W8:W117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest1).Range("D112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource2).Range("L8:M117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest2).Range("A112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource2).Range("R8:R117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest2).Range("C112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource2).Range("W8:W117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest2).Range("D112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource3).Range("L8:M117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest3).Range("A112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource3).Range("R8:R117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest3).Range("C112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource3).Range("W8:W117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest3).Range("D112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource4).Range("L8:M117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest4).Range("A112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource4).Range("R8:R117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest4).Range("C112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource4).Range("W8:W117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest4).Range("D112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource5).Range("L8:M117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest5).Range("A112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource5).Range("R8:R117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest5).Range("C112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource5).Range("W8:W117").Copy
cwb.Sheets(SheetDest5).Range("D112").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


Done:
MsgBox "Information loaded!"
Exit Sub
eh:
MsgBox "The following error occurred because XLS structure for selected month is not standard or data does not exist."



End Sub
```

I have simplified the code, focusing only in `SheetDest5`, as follows, but the problem persists:

```
Sub CopySheets()
On Error GoTo eh
Dim Path As String
Dim FileA As String
Dim FileB As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Filename2 As String
Dim SheetSource5 As String
Dim SheetDest5 As String

'Defining Strings

Path = Sheets("Config").Range("C2").Value
FileA = Sheets("Selection").Range("G23").Value
FileB = Sheets("Selection").Range("H23").Value
Filename = Path & FileA & ".xlsx"
Filename2 = Path & FileB & ".xlsx"

SheetSource5 = "MS5"
SheetDest5 = "GCCO"

'Defining Current Workbook

Set cwb = ThisWorkbook

'First Import

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename)


wbk.Worksheets(SheetSource5).Range("L8:M117").Copy
cwb.Sheets("GCCO").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you go through your code in steps using `F8`. And can you return the values of `cwb` and `SheetDest5` before pasting? Also what is the current selected sheet?

Comment: Nothing obvious. Comment out the On Error line to see if anything pops up.

Comment: in this line `Dim Path, FileA, FileB, Filename, Filename2, SheetSource1, SheetSource2, 
SheetSource3, SheetSource4, SheetSource5, SheetDest1, SheetDest2, 
SheetDest3, SheetDest4, SheetDest5 As String` only the last variable is a string.

Comment: Have you tried using the `worksheets` collection like you have when using `thisworkbook`

Comment: @JvdV, `cwb` is the workbook in which the macro is running. `SheetDest5` is the "GCCO". But the issue persists. I shortened the code focusing only in this sheet, and it still pastes in "Selection". This is a nonsense.

Comment: @SJR, nothing pops up.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, I've corrected it and still have the same issue.

Comment: is it just the `SheetDest5` ones for `filename2` that is giving the error?  Try `wbk.close 0` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Close False`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, it's just `SheetDest5` one for `Filename` that's pasting contents in `Range("A1")`. I've tried with `wbk.close 0` and it remains the same. This is crazy.

Comment: Did you correct to `Worksheets` rather than `sheets`?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, yes, I've corrected it. Results are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After review the code so many times, testing the modifications suggested in the comments, I disabled all the add-ins running on Excel. Finally, the cause of the misbehavior was "SAP Analysis for Office", not the code.